# how to set timer in a loop based on response time?

Tags: java, timer, jmeter

I'm trying to archive the following test with a loop of 50 HTTP requests:

- when the response of the current request is received, the next request is made
- if the response is not completed within 60 seconds, the current request is terminated and the next request is executed.

I have already put a loop and a constant timer in it. The problem with constant timer is that it does not care about the request's response. Hence each request is executed based on a constant time rather than each other's result.

Please help me if you know how to. Thanks alot.

Comment: You can show your code and maybe someone will push you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use response timeouts, not Timers here. Set Response Timeout to 60 seconds and that's it.